# Spring boot quartz on many instances

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I run quartz on two instances synchronized by oracle database and this is my yml configuration
I using Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.0

```
quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
      comment-prefix: '#'
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO
            jmx:
              export: true
          jobStore:
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
            tablePrefix: QRTZ_
            isClustered: true
            clusterCheckinInterval: 1000
            useProperties: false
            dataSource: quartzDataSource
          dataSource:
            quartzDataSource:
              provider: hikaricp
              driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
              URL: ${spring.datasource.url}
              user: ${spring.datasource.username}
              password: ${spring.datasource.password}
```

on one instance work properly but when I run the second instance I got this error. Does anyone have an idea about which table is missing?

```
o.s.s.q.LocalDataSourceJobStore ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failure identifying failed 

instances when checking-in: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failure identifying failed instances when checking-in: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.findFailedInstances(JobStoreSupport.java:3405) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.clusterCheckIn(JobStoreSupport.java:3455) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3315) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3920) [quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3957) [quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectSchedulerStateRecords(StdJDBCDelegate.java:2994) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.findFailedInstances(JobStoreSupport.java:3369) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar!/:12.2.0.1.0]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

In db I have those tables:

- qrtz_calendars
- qrtz_fired_triggers
- qrtz_blob_triggers
- qrtz_cron_triggers
- qrtz_simple_triggers
- qrtz_simprop_triggers
- qrtz_triggers
- qrtz_job_details
- qrtz_paused_trigger_grps
- qrtz_locks
- qrtz_scheduler_state

Comment: StdJDBCDelegate.selectSchedulerStateRecords queries qrtz_scheduler_state table which is present in your Quartz JDBC job store. My guess is that the database schema containing the job store tables is not the default schema of the Oracle user that you use on the problematic node. The Oracle user can log in, but searches a different schema, not the schema containing your job store tables. You can easily verify this by logging in from SQL Developer using the configured Oracle login credentials and running "select count(*) from qrtz_scheduler_state". If it fails, you have the problem I described.

Comment: query returned correct value

Comment: In that case a debugger is your friend. Place a breakpoint in StdJDBCDelegate.selectSchedulerStateRecords and take it from there.

Comment: perhaps you could reset the quartz tables with a fresh, up to date schema for quartz tables